# google-apps-script how to avoid repeating code?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 10 different google sheets. I have a very basic google apps script to apply to all of these. This is the script:

```
function myRecalculate() { 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet ID');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7"); 
var cell = sheet.getRange('A1') 
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
cell.setValue(number) 

}
```

And I want this to be used in 9 other sheets as well. Is there a way in GAS to avoid repeating this code 10 times? I could just copy paste and alter the sheet ID every time, but does not feel right.

Is there a simple solution?

**edit.** Solved it myself with packing all sheetID's in an array, and loop the function through the array:

```
function myRecalculate() { 

var idBE = "id of spreadsheet1"
var idDE = "id of spreadsheet2"
var idFR = "id of spreadsheet3"

// pack them in array
var id = [idBE, idDE, idFR]

// loop through array, do something with sheet
for (i in id){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id[i])

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7"); 
var cell = sheet.getRange('A1') 
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
cell.setValue(number) 
}}
```

Comment: I noticed you unaccepted the answer. If you have another answer, then please post it and accept that. I'm a bit curious why libraries does not work for you?

Comment: Hi - i used a loop with an array of sheets, and it works a lot better than libraries for easy functions. I've added the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use libraries!

Here is the reference for Apps Script libraries: [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)

**Note**: Code ran through libraries is not as fast as code ran directly from your project.

In short, you can create a version of your code by going to `File -> Manage Versions`. Save a new version. Then go to `File -> Project Properties` and copy the `Project Key`.

Go to your next Apps Script project, and go to `Resources -> Libraries`. Paste your project key into the `Find a Library` text field and click `Select`. Select the version of you're library that you want to use and hit save.

You can now reference the code in that Apps Script project like: `MyProject.myRecalculate()`